# Static files are being processed by Windsor and throwing errors if not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I just noticed that static files are being processed (I guess that is normal) but the problem is if a file doesn't exist it seems to be causing an exception here:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
        {
            this._kernel = kernel;
        }

        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
            }
            return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
    }
```

Specifically the GetControllerInstance.

Does this make sense?  Should I put extra checks in there to make sure it is a class being processed?

The error:

```
The controller for path '/Assets/img/logo.png' could not be found.
```

Comment: Don't you mean [tag:caslte-windsor]? (As in widsor with an `n` added?)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [excluding static files](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx) from being processed by ASP.NET MVC engine to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

If controllerType is null, pass it to the base class or return null

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this._kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);

        return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Ninjet sample: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc2/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectControllerFactory.cs